# How to create a two-way binding in blazor using the RenderTreeBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-core, binding, blazor, .net-6.0, mudblazor

I would like to know how to implement a two-way-binding in blazor using the `RenderTreeBuilder`. Therefore I created the following minimalistic example to discuss about a solution

```
<MudForm @ref="@_Form" @bind-IsValid="@IsValid">@ChildContent</MudForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> IsValidChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private MudForm _Form;
}
```

I would like to reimplement the blazor code concerning the `MudForm` using the `RenderTreeBuilder`. I face difficulties as I want to implement the `bind-IsValid`-attribute. I have no idea on how to implement this two-way-binding. My implementation so far looks like following

```
    private RenderFragment formControl => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<MudForm>(0);
        builder.AddAttribute(1, nameof(MudForm.IsValid), IsValid);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, nameof(MudForm.IsValidChanged), EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(this, value => IsValid = value, IsValid));
        builder.AddAttribute(3, nameof(MudForm.ChildContent), ChildContent);
        builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(4, (value) => { _Form = (MudForm)value; });
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
```

Is the use of the `EventCallback.Factory` correct? Does anyone have an idea on how to implement such a two way binding to a property using the `RenderTreeBuilder`?

Comment: Look at the generated source for the razor file and copy that.

Comment: You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69137525/bunit-2-way-binding), maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the solution by checking the generated file. Here is what I did:

1. I added following attribute to the *.csproj*-file of the corresponding project and built the project.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. Go to the generated files (e.g. */obj/Debug/net6.0/generated/....*)
3. Go to the corresponding file ending on *.g.cs* and check the generated code of the `RenderTreeBuilder`.
4. Following code was generated by the razor compiler

   ```
   builder.AddAttribute(2, nameof(MudForm.IsValidChanged), EventCallback.Factory.Create<bool>(this, value => { IsValid = value; }));
   ```