# bUnit not updating bound property

Tags: testing, data-binding, blazor, bunit

I wrote a Blazor Client component which I'm trying to test using a bUnit .razor test.

The component contains a text input that is bound to a `MyValue` property. The input listens to `@onkeyup` event and adds the `MyValue` value to a List when Enter key is pressed.

The input element looks like this:
`<input type="text" @bind-value="MyValue" @bind-value:event="onchange" @onkeyup="InputOnKeyUp"/>`

The `InputOnKeyUp` handler looks like this:

```
private void InputOnKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
    {
        var trimmed = MyValue.Trim();

        if (!model.MyList.Contains(trimmed) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed))
            model.MyList.Add(trimmed);

        MyValue = "";
    }
}
```

I am accessing the input element in the bUnit test with `.Find` function, like so:
`var textBox = cut.Find("input");`

When passing keys from bUnit, the `MyValue` property, which the input is bound to, doesn't get updated, even though the application works as expected. I am passing the keys like so:

```
var textBox = cut.Find("input");
textBox.KeyUp("v");
textBox.KeyUp("a");
textBox.KeyUp("l");
textBox.KeyUp(Key.Space);
textBox.KeyUp("1");
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69137525/bunit-2-way-binding) that I should use the change event, but I need access to the key that is pressed, so I can't go that way.

[EDIT] I'm including the entire test file:

```
@code {
    public void HappyPath()
    {
        using var ctx = new TestContext();
        ctx.Services.AddScoped<IJsApiService, JsApiService>();

        var values = new List<string>();

        var cut = ctx.Render(@<MyComponent MyValues="values"/>);

        cut.Find(".mud-chip-content").TextContent.Should().Be("val 1");
        
        var textBox = cut.Find("input");

        textBox.KeyUp("v");
        textBox.KeyUp("a");
        textBox.KeyUp("l");
        textBox.KeyUp(Key.Space);
        textBox.KeyUp("2");

        textBox.KeyUp(Key.Enter);

        var chips = cut.FindAll(".mud-chip-content");
        chips.Count.Should().Be(2);
        chips.Last().TextContent.Should().Be("val 2");

        values.Count.Should().Be(2);
        values.Last().Should().Be("val 2");

        cut.Find(".mud-chip-close-button").Click();

        chips.Count.Should().Be(1);
        cut.Find(".mud-chip-content").TextContent.Should().Be("val 2");

        values.Count.Should().Be(1);
        values.First().Should().Be("val 2");
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you show the whole test including the setup and your expectation?

You never "entered" something in the textBox itself - `KeyUp` just triggers the `onkeyup` event, but it doesn't actually enters the characters in your input textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyUp` method of bUnit will just invoke your `onkeyup` event that is attached to your `input` element. It will **not** enter the characters one-by-one like an end-to-end testing framework like playwright.

Therefore you have to go with the approach, as you already mentioned, of using `Change`:

```cs
// Arrange
var textBox = cut.Find("input");
textBox.Change("val 1");

// Act
textBox.KeyUp(Key.Enter);

// Assert
AssertMyValueIsInModel();
```

At least from the code you provided your `onkeyup` doesn't have any other side-effects. So the given code will put the "val 1" into the input box that is bound to `MyValue` and when we raise the `onkeyup` event, we'll add the value to the model's list.